# Is there any way to get 30 individual days of data in one call using the New York Times Most Popular API?

Tags: api

It gives options for the most popular articles over the last 30, 7, or 1 days. What I'm hoping to find is the most popular articles of each day for the last 30 days. So far the only way I know to do this is to find the most recent 1 day's most popular articles 30 days in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. There is no archive aspect to the Most Popular API. You would have to make daily calls for the next 30 days and store the response. After that you would be able to continue as normal as long as you continued the daily request.

You should, if you haven't already, post about this in the NYT Dev forum:
http://developer.nytimes.com/forum

Its possible that if this is requested by others there would be a push to implement it.